# Iterate javascript object doesn't work via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is like this:

```
$(obj).each(function(i, prop) { 
    tr.append('<td>'+ i +'</td>' + '<td>'+ prop +'</td>');
});
```

Interestingly my data in $(obj) is like this

```
Object {id:1234, Name:"Johnson".....};
```

instead of

```
{id:1234, Name:"Johnson".....};
```

meaning it is an object instead of an array, but I don't think it should be different. Above iteration always only return:

```
i: 0
prop: Object {id:1234, Name:"Johnson".....};
```

looks like jQuery failed to extract properties from Object

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is for wrapping DOM elements. You can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for iterating arrays and objects.

```
$.each(obj, function(i, prop) {
    tr.append('<td>'+ i +'</td>' + '<td>'+ prop +'</td>');
});
```